# GKE node pool doesn't scale up

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a GKE cluster which doesn't scale up when a particular deployment needs more resources.
I've checked the cluster autoscaler logs and it has entries with this error:
`no.scale.up.nap.pod.zonal.resources.exceeded`. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-autoscaler-visibility#noscaleup-reasons) for this error says:

> Node auto-provisioning did not provision any node group for the Pod in
> this zone because doing so would violate resource limits.

I don't quite understand which resource limits are mentiond in the documentation and why it prevents node-pool from scaling up?

If I scale cluster up manually - deployment pods are scaled up and everything works as expected, so, seems it's not a problem with project quotas.

Comment: Did you check the quota page?

Comment: Yes, no quotas close to limits. Also scaling cluster manually works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [Limits for clusters](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-provisioning#limits_for_clusters) that you define are enforced based on the total CPU and memory resources used across your cluster, not just auto-provisioned pools.
- When you are not using node auto provisioning (NAP), [disable node auto provisioning feature for the cluster.](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-provisioning#disable)
- When you are using NAP, then [update the cluster wide resource](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-provisioning#enable) limits defined in NAP for the cluster .
- Try a workaround by specifying the [machine type explicitly](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-provisioning#custom_machine_family) in the workload spec. Ensure to use a supported machine family with GKE node auto-provisioning

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to experiment with these settings